# Puppeteer does not use cache when connected to proxy

Tags: caching, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I have a task that opens a browser and then visits the same page over and over again.
After testing network usage I've noticed that without proxies it caches files just fine, but as soon as I am connecting to a proxy it stops caching.
I am using rotating proxies with different ip:port for each worker and I wonder what should I do  in order to save the precious data.

Comment: hi there, did you find the cause of the problem? I assume the issue is the proxy server itself, isn't it?